# Unable to load firebase realtime database data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For the past 5-6 days i have been unable to view my project real time database data. I always have this blank data page like the one in the image attached. Can someone guide me on what could be the possible issue with my firebase console[image]

Comment: Have you see console log for this issue ?

Comment: How do I see the console log for  real time database cause I only access that of cloud functions

Comment: I am taking about browser console if something suspicious found.

Comment: No. I am using it for an android app. I still access the data there but I am unable to view it from console.firebase.google.com

Comment: well try manually create one record it is visible or not ?

Comment: sorry I don't understand your response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157962/discussion-between-sanjay-radadiya-and-green-onyeji).

Comment: where is @Frank van Puffelen https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen ? please come and help

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by downloading the latest browser